# Elliptic Curve addition: Tangent Point

Tags: elliptic-curves

Considering the "visual" method of explaining elliptic curve addition, I wonder what you are supposed to do if one of the points being added is tangent to the curve?

With the classic shape e.g.  $y^2 = x^3 - x + 2$ , you could get a horizontal line, that only touches the curve twice, not three times:

[image]

The third point can't be $0$, because that would mean that $B=-A$, clearly not the case. It can't be $B$ either, because that would mean that $A=0$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How can a point be tangent to a curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we would say that your straight line passes through the points:
$$ [{\rm Blue}], \ \ [{\rm Red } ], \ \ [{\rm Red}].$$
Notice that I've deliberately included the point $[{\rm Red } ]$ **twice** in this list! This is because the straight line intersects the elliptic curve with **multiplicity two** at the point $[{\rm Red } ]$.

The rest is standard: having identified these three(!) intersections points between the straight line and the elliptic curve, we deduce the group addition rule:
$$ [{\rm Blue}] + [{\rm Red}] = - [{\rm Red}]$$

Comment: Very clear, thanks Kenny!